# nappo - probably dotnet command missing

Tags: fedora, rpm, .net

I know that this is a question for beginners, but I cannot find the `nappo` command. It's used in the Fedora packaging script for ARM 64 DotNet. I tried to google it, yum search, pkgs.org, repology and GitHub.

The file where the nappo command is used is here: https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/dotnet6.0/blob/rawhide/f/build-arm64-bootstrap-tarball

Comment: I am really unaware of such a command. I digged alot, and all I could find is some Pytorch library, that had a github repository but it's been deleted. It's related to machine learning, so this looks like an alias of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nappo is a custom command used by the Fedora project to pack dotnet.** I e-mailed an author and he was very helpful by sending me this gist:

https://gist.github.com/omajid/c04b6025de49d0b7b18ab4a7e789484e

I decided to patch in for Enterprise Linux 8 in my repo: https://github.com/AlexBaranowski/nappo